# Implementing Bittorrent Protocol

Tags: protocols, bittorrent

I am looking for a tutorial/blog post on how to implement bittorrent protocol step by step.
How it works? How do you make requests to peers? and talk to trackers.

I do not mind the programming language (java,ruby,perl,c#)

Comment: I am interested in this and feel there has got to be some better knowledge out there so I put a bounty up. I'm looking for tutorials / walkthroughs of the protocol but any starting out pointers would be nice to see too.

Answer (score 28):

the complete description of bittorrent protocol:

http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html

Comment: jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html is a terrible source about the BitTorrent protocol. Parts of it is very convoluted and other parts is outright wrong. A better source is the inofficial specification here: https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification or the official here: http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html

Comment: The link you provided is no longer accessible, which renders the whole answer useless now. Would you like to update it? perhaps adding some short details into the post itself?

Answer (score 24):

There is the [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/index.html) library.

Here's the [API documentation](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html) and [examples](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/examples.html).

Answer (score 11):

This is good source http://www.kristenwidman.com/blog/how-to-write-a-bittorrent-client-part-1/
She explains the process step by step...

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest you look [at the spec](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) and sources of some OSS clients. You'll have to do some work, but that's how programming works.

Answer (score 8):

I'm currently implementing a BitTorrent client in Java using [this](http://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification) specification.

Comment: Have you completed the implementation? If so, is it open source?

Answer (score 4):

Qt is very easy to read so you can read the [Qt Torrent Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-torrent-example.html) (C++)

Answer (score 4):

Implementing the protocol is not that hard by following the specs. However, there are lots of internal things like storage, scalable server, peer/piece pick algorithm, etc.

Earlier BitTorrent implementation or [BitTornado](http://www.bittornado.com) used python, which is easy to read. I personally found them useful to understand the internals.

Answer (score 3):

This is a implementation of the bittorrent protocol done in .NET. Its source code is available on github and it has documentation

[Monotorrent](http://www.monotorrent.com/)