# Why does tracker server NOT understand my request? (Bittorrent protocol)

Tags: c, bittorrent

I'm trying to implement Bittorent in C. First of all, before writing a code snippet,  I tried to used a web browser to send the following message(URL) to the tracker server.

you may try this URL.

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?
info_hash=%9b%db%bbI%f0%85%a2%d1%5d%96%ac%fa%bf%f81%06%001O%e0
&peer_id=ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD&port=6882&downloaded=0
&uploaded=0
&left=0
&event=started
```

I have downloaded the torrent file from [this link](http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969) which is named *dapper-dvd-i386.iso* and has `9bdbbb49f085a2d15d96acfabff8310600314fe0` as SHA-1 value.

However, after sending above request, I get

```
your client is outdated, please upgrade
(HTTP 400 bad request)
```

Why does tracker server NOT understand my reqeust? Any specs from Internet does not help me.
Any help would be awesome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include the code you use to generate your request.

Comment: When I tried C code, I got the same result as web browser. you may try above URL using your web browser.

Comment: @jxh I think something would be wrong with URL. So I want someone to correct my URL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because the request string don't have `compact=1` in it.
Most tracker require that nowadays. The legacy way is too ineffective.

See BEP 23: Tracker Returns Compact Peer Lists http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html

Try:

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?
info_hash=%9b%db%bbI%f0%85%a2%d1%5d%96%ac%fa%bf%f81%06%001O%e0
&peer_id=ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD&port=6882&downloaded=0
&uploaded=0
&left=0
&event=started
&compact=1
```

ie

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%9b%db%bbI%f0%85%a2%d1%5d%96%ac%fa%bf%f81%06%001O%e0&peer_id=ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD&port=6882&downloaded=0&uploaded=0&left=0&event=started&compact=1
```

and the answer from the tracker is:

```
d8:completei4e10:incompletei0e8:intervali1800e5:peers6:******e
```