# Sending Bittorrent HTTP request to Ubuntu tracker

Tags: http, http-get, bittorrent

I downloaded the torrent file of ubuntu 17.10 from here:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Here is what inside:

```
TorrentInfo{Created By: null
Main tracker: http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce
Comment: Ubuntu CD releases.ubuntu.com
Info_hash: f07e0b0584745b7bcb35e98097488d34e68623d0
Name: ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso
Piece Length: 524288
Pieces: 2866
Total Size: 1502576640
Is Single File Torrent: true
File List: 
Tracker List: 
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce
http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce
```

What I have tried:

I sent: (Only torrent info-hash)

> http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%f0%7e%0b%05%84%74%5b%7b%cb%35%e9%80%97%48%8d%34%e6%86%23%d0

and received:

> you sent me garbage - id not of length 20

I sent: (torrent info-hash and my peer-id)

> http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%f0%7e%0b%05%84%74%5b%7b%cb%35%e9%80%97%48%8d%34%e6%86%23%d0&peer_id=%2D%41%5A%35%37%35%30%2D%54%70%6B%58%74%74%5A%4C%66%70%53%48

and received:

> you sent me garbage - invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''

---

## What am I missing? The spec doesn't specify any example.

Spec:

https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *announce* misses the obligatory keys **port**, **uploaded**, **downloaded** and **left**.
These keys plus **info_hash** and **peer_id**, MUST be in every *announce*.

Further, while the **event** key isn't obligatory in every *announce*,
the first *announce* to the tracker MUST include '**event=started**'.

Trying:

> http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%f0%7e%0b%05%84%74%5b%7b%cb%35%e9%80%97%48%8d%34%e6%86%23%d0&peer_id=%2D%41%5A%35%37%35%30%2D%54%70%6B%58%74%74%5A%4C%66%70%53%48&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=1502576640&event=started

and the tracker responses with:

> your client is outdated, please upgrade

oh well, more to fix...

From my answer here: [Why does tracker server NOT understand my request? (Bittorrent protocol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418004/why-does-tracker-server-not-understand-my-request-bittorrent-protocol/24001128#24001128)

> It is because the request string don't have **compact=1** in it.
>    Most tracker require that nowadays. The legacy way is too ineffective.

So, adding  **compact=1** to the *announce*:

> http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%f0%7e%0b%05%84%74%5b%7b%cb%35%e9%80%97%48%8d%34%e6%86%23%d0&peer_id=%2D%41%5A%35%37%35%30%2D%54%70%6B%58%74%74%5A%4C%66%70%53%48&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=1502576640&event=started&compact=1

and the tracker responses with:

> d8:completei2134e10:incompletei100e8:intervali1800e5:peers300:[ binary data ... ]e

Success!

Comment: Thanks so much! How can I read the binary data? which encoding is that?

Comment: I got different result then you got: `d8:completei2583e12:crypto_flags50:                                                  10:incompletei118e8:intervali1800e5:peers300:¹æ}-ß[¹”}åÇI…?!áNƒo‹‹°?²MÈÕÄ6)0©ŒTõ
ÿÔ\|vh®N]á_ˆa}Þ;%»mYÇ©NÁX;å¹Ù1Ì7ÙÅ =.À™ê[Æ^SÔgºÈÕ]‹–L]¦l=ªlâVe\
“KŠJ@·àÀƒ,4èîä`ŽAñV“R+ÈÕW{ ÈÕRÿ×Ð^ègñ="ÈÕ¬Ò®á.ö&íÈÕ`Yù“ÈÕQ"@x#''P”ÈÕQ«IàÂA·LKê`Sý~;È[<ÌÔ1Yæ¾0ÈÕ\ùòzb¤36Ù¼ZpFÈÕ—P]DÙ.ImÈÕ¹ÙÓ‘3ÿ\½_V¾ËÈ×B7ÎDê``Q>±áÀƒ,)IHBœÈÕ²,”ÿÛ›]¨PÛïe` Why?

Comment: The binary data is a string consisting of multiples of 6 bytes. First 4 bytes are the IP address and last 2 bytes are the port number. All in big endian notation. See the wiki or BEP23. The key: **crypto_flags** is sent by the tracker if a peer sent **supportcrypto=1** or **requirecrypto=1** in the *announce*.See: http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Message_Stream_Encryption